# create new table for each row problems

Tags: mysql

I have an android app that in many parts of it , users vote for comments and choices in different articles . I create new table for each users but I understood that it occupy much space.
the recorded numbers consists of numbers 1 to 15 and id of articles.
What should I Do?

Comment: if all of those tables are essentially identical in structure, then it's a bad design. why not have **ONE** table, and add 'userID' as a field in that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a Users table, article table and UserArticleTableXref. Store Users in users table  and articles in article table and when the users vote / comment on an article reference the UserID and article ID in the UserArticleTableXref to store your comments and ratings.